# unable to access the api path localhost:1337/auth/local always return not found in strappi

Tags: next.js, strapi, nuxt-strapi

I installed a fresh strapi project and trying to authenticate api using jwt token.but the auth/local api always return not found

Comment: Can you provide more context and code? You need to send the post request with the identifier and the password in the body.

Comment: i already includes these credentials in the body.but return 404

Comment: Can you share the code where you are sending the request? Are you adding the localhost:1337 at the start?

Comment: http://localhost:1337/auth/local and in body {
    "identifier": "testp@gmail.com",
    "password" : "123456"
}  result in not found in postman

Comment: Can you show the error message you are getting in the postman? Are you getting a 404 not found or no user found message?

Comment: i am getting 404 not found error

Comment: check your URL, it should start with http, http://localhost:1337/auth/local and make sure your strapi server is running at http://localhost:1337

Comment: i tried the same http://localhost:1337/auth/local  in body and pass the identifier and password.but return not found and also in my project  in api folder users folder not created

Comment: did you add "http://" infront of your url?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Issue Solved.I am upgrate to strapi version 3.6.8 to version 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

`/auth/local` will only respond to a `POST` request.

Any other HTTP Request (GET, DELETE, UPDATE etc) will be sent a 404 status (Not found).

Make sure you are sending a HTTP POST request.